# Is there a way to check if two lists have the same type of elements in Java?

Tags: java, list, equals

I have a `MyDoublyLinkedList<E>` which works essentially like the usual DLLs without dummies. I want to write an `equals(Object obj)` method for the class, and I realized that I can only check for the type of `obj` with `obj instanceof MyDoublyLinkedList`, but not `obj instanceof MyDoublyLinkedList<E>`.

If any of the two lists I'm comparing has elements, I can simply check for the elements and I'll know their type. But Let's say both lists are empty, but have different element types (e.g. `MyDoublyLinkedList<String>` and `MyDoublyLinkedList<Integer>`. I know that array lists will consider two of such lists equal, but for my list I want them to be not equal, because one list is meant to contain strings while the other is meant to contain integers.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You could create a `StringDoublyLinkedList` which extends `MyDoublyLinkedList<String>`. Same for `Integer`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Agree. Otherwise, you will not be able to retrieve it because of `type erasure` in Java for generics. If not generic type, you could use `obj.getClass().getComponentType();`

Comment: Another way is to have the class of the element as a property of MyDoubleLinkedList. The downsize is that you'll have to pass it when constructing the MyDoubleLinkedList. This can be mitigated with static methods used as factories (like createForString() or createForInteger()).

Comment: I see. So in short this can't be done with generic types because of type erasure, so the only way to do it is to know the types in advance and create subclasses for it, or pass extra information into the class :( Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at the way [`ArrayList::equals`](https://github.com/adoptium/jdk20/blob/82749901b1497f524e53e47c45708c8e4a63c8b9/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L516) is implemented, to get an idea on how to implement yours

Comment: @smac89 as I have explained, my `equals` method works differently with that of the `ArrayList` in the example I have provided. If you compare two empty ArrayLists with different types, `ArrayList.equals()` will return `true`.

Comment: You could also pass the class to a constructor, e.g. `new MyDoublyLinkedList(String.class)` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I saw:

In short this can't be done with generic types because of type erasure, so the only way to do it is to know the types in advance and create subclasses for it, or pass extra information into the class :(

Comment: Not entirely true, see my comment. Although type erasure does prevent knowing some information in advance, but it is definitely possible to create a generic `equals` method without knowing the types or resorting to reflection.

Comment: This is correct.  Without other information passed on, the two lists with different types will be represented exactly the same in every way as far as Java is concerned at runtime.